# How to download a full HTML page as pdf using DOMPDF?

Tags: php, dompdf, html2pdf

I used dompdf to download a receipt that is initially in HTML format. But as soon as it gets converted, the orientation and the format gets distorted. Is there  way to download an HTML page as pdf with the same height and width as the HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. Every html->pdf tool are different. some doesnt allow css some allow html5 but very bad. some allow gif etc. lots of variations. You shouldnt look for a tool that render the html page and convert to pdf. You should find something like view the page and get its screenshots of it and print as pdf. because today's complex html pages are just too overwhelming for html->pdf tools. Those tools are made for html coders to create fancy pdfs.

Try to search browser plug-ins. If you find one you can automatize the process via linux konsole. (fire-fox, maybe chrome too not sure though)

Comment: Actually i want to link a button and on clicking it, the whole page would be converted into pdf. Actually it is possible. The official websites like SSC and UPSC uses it. Its just you and I doesn't know.

Comment: I dont know those sites but i told you. It is possible but dont search for tools that renders the page and make a pdf file. search for tools that take the image, the view of the page and to create a pdf.

Comment: http://convertwebpage.com/ see here. you need to find a local standalone program of this. What you are looking for is RENDERS the html code. IT shouldn't render. It should just take the photo of the page.

Comment: I tried all other things and am successful in rendering page, images, and tables. But I just want to do that for what I've asked for.

Comment: This is good and somewhat helpful. But where can I get the code to convert HTML to a image ?